# Call a function daily at fix time in my web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, function

I want to call a function daily at 11:00 pm to check due payments for my all users 
how can I call this function?
problem is that I cant use Task schedules as I am using shared server and I am also using IIS 7 
my web site is in .Net and C#

Comment: I would create a daemon process who fires at  desired time. Do you need to call a stored procedure or something like that?

Comment: I don't get why you can't use a scheduled task, could you not schedule a task that only targets your users?

Comment: Also, is it a DB task?  If so there may be a DBMS facility available to use.

Comment: I have created a procedure and afuction for it which is working fine as i have written code to call tha in Global.asax file but it is working on windows xp (IIS 6 but not on IIS7)

Comment: create a windows application(scheduler kind of) and update payment details.

Comment: how can i use that windows application on shared server

Answer (score 2):

There are several tools for this. Check out [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). Another solution might be to schedule a job on SQL Server, if that's something you're using, and depending on what you want the job to do.

That is, assuming that you really can't use the Task scheduler. It's pretty reliable, and easy to work with, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a Global Timer or create a background thread and put the task code in the background thread's worker function.

However, both of them rely on the asp.net application being alive(not shut down).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to create a custom Schedule. It'd write to a file or a database a list of the tasks it must complete, them use a Timer to run the tasks and mark them as completed as they're done.

The algorithm is something like:

Each X minutes:

1. Check datasource for pending tasks.
2. Execute a task
3. Schedule the same task for tomorrow
4. Mark task as completed.
5. Next task.

Answer (score 0):

Build a secured web page that performs this function and call it from an external system such as your own PC.

Answer (score 0):

using Windows Service solved this issue